# Limiting Resource Usage for an IP on a Shared Host

Tags: php, mysql, resources

Recently, I had a single IP call the same page 15,000 times in quick succession which used up a lot of server resources (with resulting warning email from Host service). I am on a shared host so can't load new modules and therefore have no real options to truly limit bandwidth to an IP.

So, I'm trying to figure out how I can use the least amount of resources in spotting an offending IP and redirecting it to a 403 Forbidden page. I am already checking for common hacks and using Project HoneyPot, but to do this for each of the 15,000 page hits is not efficient (and, like this one, it doesn't catch them all).

I currently log access to each page to a mysql table called `visitors`. I can imagine a couple of ways to go about this:

**Option 1: Using MySql:**
1) Query the `visitors` table for the number of hits from the IP over the last 10 seconds.
2) If greater than a certain number (15?), flag the last entry in `visitors` as blocked for this IP.
3) With each subsequent page request, the query on the `visitors` table will show the ip as blocked and I can then redirect to 403 Forbidden page.

**Option 2: Modifying an Include File on the fly which contains blacklisted IPs:**
1) `Include` a file which returns an array of blacklisted IPs
2) If the current IP is not on the list, query the `visitors` table as in Option 1 to see if the number of hits from the IP over the last 10 seconds is greater than a certain number.
3) If the IP is offending, modify the `include` file to include this IP address as shown below.

In essence, my question is: Which uses more resources (x 15,000): a query to the database, or the code below which uses `include` to read a file and then array_search(), OR is there a better way to do this?

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$filename='__blacklist.php';

if (file_exists($filename)){
    // get array of excluded ip addresses
    $array = (include $filename);
    // if current address is in list, send to 403 forbidden page
    var_dump($array);

    if (is_array($array) && array_search($ip, $array) !== false){
    blockAccess("Stop Bugging Me!");
    }
} else {
    echo "$filename does not exist";
}

// evaluate some condition which if true will cause IP to be added to blacklist - this will be a query to a MySql table determining number of hits to the site over a period of time like the last 10 seconds.
if (TRUE){
    blockip($ip);
}

// debug - let's see what is blocked
// $array = (include $filename);
// var_dump($array);    

// add the ip to the blacklist
function blockip($ip){
    $filename='__blacklist.php';
    if (! file_exists($filename)){
    // create the include file
    $handle = fopen($filename, "w+");
    // write beginning of file - 111.111.111.111 is a placeholder so all new ips can be added
    fwrite($handle, '<?php return array("111.111.111.111"');
    } else {
    // let's block the current IP
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r+');
    // Don't use filesize() on files that may be accessed and updated by parallel processes or threads 
    // (as the filesize() return value is maintained in a cache).
    // use fseek & ftell instead
    fseek($handle, 0 ,SEEK_END);
    $filesize = ftell($handle);

    if ($filesize > 20){
        // remove ); from end of file so new ip can be added
        ftruncate($handle, $filesize-2);

        // go to end of file
        fseek($handle, 0 ,SEEK_END);

    } else {
        // invalid file size - truncate file
        $handle = fopen($filename, "w+");
        // write beginning of file with a placeholder so a new ip can be added
        fwrite($handle, '<?php return array("111.111.111.111"');
    }
    }

    //add new ip and closing of array
    fwrite($handle, "," . PHP_EOL . '"' . $ip . '");');


    fclose($handle);
}


    function blockAccess($message) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset='UTF-8' />\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n" .
    "<h1>Forbidden</h1><p>You don't have access to this page.</p>" . 
    "\n</body>\n</html>";
    die();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of points to address here.

## Query vs Include

This is basically going to come down to the server its hosted on. Shared hosting is not known for good IO and you will have to test this. This also depends on how many IPs you will be blacklisting.

## Blocking Malicious IPs

Ideally you don't want malicious users to hit PHP once you determine that they are malicious. The only real way to do that in a shared environment on apache is to block them from htaccess. Its not recommended but it is possible to modify htaccess from PHP.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

## Caching

The main concern I have from reading your question is that you seem to not understand the problem. If you are receiving 15,000 hits in a timeframe of seconds, you should not have 15,000 database connections and you should not have all of those requests hitting PHP. You need to cache these requests. If this is happening your system is fundamentally flawed. It should not be physically possible for 1 user on home internet to spike your resource usage that much.

## Shared hosting is a bad idea

I suggest in your situation to get a VPS or something else that will allow you to use a reverse proxy and employ far more caching/blacklisting/resource monitoring.

Comment: 15000 hits were over a few minutes at about 4 per second. The database connection issue was the reason I knew I had to come up with a different solution. I agree that avoiding PHP requests is what I need. I also thought about modifying `.htaccsss` for the same reasons but knew it wasn't recommended. What I could do is periodically monitor how many addresses get added to .htaccess and manually move them over to an include file (and remove from `.htaccess`), since these kind of attacks from an IP usually don't reoccur from the same IP. Changing hosts is not an option at this time due to cost.

Comment: There are plenty of VPS's that are in the exact same price range as shared hosting. OVH, Ramnode, I can name plenty more.

Comment: If you are stuck on shared hosting I think modifying htaccess with php is probably your best bet. A database/php solution might reduce the traffic by 10% -> 30% but if they are sending you 15000 requests in a few minutes you really just need to block them.

Comment: VPS does seem to be the way to go. It's $8/ month more - but obviously worth it. Until I am willing to pay and take the time to move to a new service, I will inplement the `.htaccess` solution. Thanks for taking the time to reply with a full answer.

Comment: OVH Classic VPS starts at $2.99/mo, Ramnode VPS starts at $1.25/mo. These services will allow you to handle like 20+ requests a second if you setup your webserver well and employ caching. They also give you full control over the webserver environment.

Comment: [This link](http://reviewsignal.com/blog/2014/06/25/40-million-hits-a-day-on-wordpress-using-a-10-vps/) may be helpful to you.